# Click anywhere link

Tags: javascript

I have a splash page and want the user to be able to click anywhere on the page and send them to the main site. I've found close solutions on SO, but my issue is that my splash page has a floating `div` in the center, so using something like `<body onclick="window.location.href='url'">` only works when clicking on the `div`, not anywhere else on the background. Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/layout.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="splash">
        <h1>PM & ASSOCIATES</h1>
        <p>Worldwide</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
.splash{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.splash p{
    font-size:12pt;
    font-family:Castellar, Garamond, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.splash h1{
    font-size:32pt;
    font-family:Castellar, Garamond, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just make the body width and height 100%?

Comment: I never knew that html & body tags did not default to 100% width/height. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least historically, I had similar issues trying to get content to take up 100% height because the `body` is only like a `div`.  It only takes up the space needed for its content.  So, to fix this, you should be able to make your html and body both 100%:

```
html { width:100%;height:100%; }
body { width:100%;height:100%; }
```

Doing this should force the body tag to take up the entire window.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. This was the easiest solution to implement, though everyone else's suggestions would probably work just as good.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather simple solution, but this could work if you're able to modify the html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/layout.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="splash">
            <h1>PM & ASSOCIATES</h1><p>Worldwide</p>
        </div>
        <a href="[insert url here]" class="fullPageLink"></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Insert your desired URL inside the link's href attribute.

Then these styles should be added:

```
body{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.fullPageLink{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You and Kevin came up with essentially the same solution at almost the same time. Gotta give it to Kevin for being a tad quicker and simpler, but good effort nonetheless!